# How to fetch checkbox (generated inside a iterator tag) values in Action Class

Tags: checkbox, struts2

**Background**

we have a list of items and each item can be selected by checking its checkbox. If a submit button is clicked after selecting all necessary checkboxes. So now, in our Action class, we could get the values of checkboxes which had been selected, by which we can store the selection check box values in Database.

**Environment:** Struts 2.3.20

When run the below mentioned code, the JSP creates the dynamic checkboxes perfectly fine. But when I select the checkboxes and hit SAVE button I get the below mentioned error. If Anybody who has encountered similar issue can share their experience on how they resolved this issue would be highly appreciated.

ERROR:

Null pointer exception at Line 54 of Action Class.

(    com.testapp.struts2.actions.AddProductsAction.execute(AddProductsAction.java:54)

addProducts.jsp :

```jsp
<s:form action="addProducts2Campaign" method="post">
 <s:iterator value="productsList" status="stat">                    
   <tr bgcolor="<s:if test="#productStatus.odd == true">#999999</s:if><s:else>#CEDDF4</s:else>">
    <td align="center">
        <s:checkbox name="selectedProductsList[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" fieldValue="%{productId}"/>
    </td>                 
    <td align="center"><s:property value="Title" /></td>
    <td align="center"><s:property value="SKU" /></td>
    <td align="center"><s:property value="Description" /></td>
    <td align="center"><s:property value="Price" /></td>
   </tr>
 </s:iterator>   
</s:form>
```

ADDPRODUCTSACTION.java

```java
public class AddProductsAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Products>{

private Products products = new Products();

private Map<Integer, Boolean> selectedProducts;

@Override
public Products getModel() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return products;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {

    ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAO();
    ArrayList<Integer> productIds2Add = new ArrayList(); 

    (Line 54:>> below)
    for (Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry : selectedProducts.entrySet()) {
        Integer key=entry.getKey();
        Boolean value=entry.getValue();
        if(value == true){
            productIds2Add.add(key);
        }
    }

   products.setProductIds2Add(productIds2Add);

   productDAO.addProducts(products);
    return IConstants.SUCCESS;
}// End of execute()



public Products getProducts() {
    return products;
}



public void setProducts(Products products) {
    this.products = products;
}


public void setSelectedProducts(Map<Integer, Boolean> selectedProducts) {
    this.selectedProducts = selectedProducts;
}


}
```

PRODUCT.JAVA

```java
public class Products {

private ArrayList<Integer> productIds2Add;

public ArrayList<Integer> getProductIds2Add() {
    return productIds2Add;
}

public void setProductIds2Add(ArrayList<Integer> productIds2Add) {
    this.productIds2Add = productIds2Add;
}
}
```

Comment: ... and line 54 is...? And what's null on that line? And why? Seems easy enough to at least diagnose the root issue. Also the rendered HTML is usually a good thing to include as a sanity check.

Comment: You don't have `productsList` or `selectedProductsList` variables in your action.

Comment: Sometimes model driven action could be used to decouple view data from the action logic but not in your case because you are missing some properties from the view layer left them unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

```
I figured out the cause. struts.xml didn't have the the input property set because of which the Model was not getting set with the values. Once I added that it worked. 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
   <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="addProducts2Campaign" method="execute" class="com.myapp.actions.AddProductsAction">
        **<result name="input">/products/addProducts.jsp</result>**
        <result name="success">/products/confirmation.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>

        </package>
    </struts>
```